# get element with specific attribute without knowing element tag name

Tags: php, xpath

I want to know how to get an element that has a specific attribute without knowing the tag name of the element. I know that in `XPath` you can write something like this:

```
//elementTag[@att="attValue"]
```

which searches for an element with the specified attribute. But is it possible to search for an element by only specifying the attribute tag name and the attribute value using `XPath`?

I am using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to use a *wildcard*:

```
//*[@att="attValue"]
```

See section [Node Tests](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) in the XSLT 1.0 spec.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about those.